# What's theoretically a good Nerdle combination?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, arithmetic, recreational-mathematics, information-theory

https://nerdlegame.com/

These are the rules of Nerdle:

- There are eight spaces for operators/digits.
- Each guess is a calculation.
- You can use 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 + - * /or =.
- It must contain one “=”.
- It must only have a number to the right of the “=”, not another
  calculation.
- Standard order of operations applies, so calculate * and / before +
  and -.

My goto is 3*54=162, so we can get information about the small/middle numbers, and see if multiplication is used. Just curious, is there any better combinations for guessing?

Comment: Without having played very much, `3*4-12=0` seems good.

Comment: @MishaLavrov Same for $7\ast8-56=0$ or $3*87=261$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's first think about digit frequency. It is hard for me to see how to brute-force all possible Nerdles, but here are a couple possible cases to illustrate some ideas:

- There are $3240$ possible equations of the form `AB+CD=EF`. Among these, the frequencies with which the digits $0$ through $9$ appear (that is, the *number of equations that contain the digit at least once*, not the total number of appearances) are: $$936, 1917, 1804, 1726, 1648, 1648, 1570, 1492, 1414, 1392$$ Equations `EF-CD=AB` will follow the same distribution.
- There are $614$ possible equations of the form `A*BC=DEF`. Among these, the frequencies with which the digits $0$ through $9$ appear are: $$170, 279, 346, 305, 326, 272, 324, 272, 303, 245$$ Equations `DEF/A = BC` will follow the same distribution.

There are other forms that the equation can take, but they will be less common, and they will probably show a similar pattern. $0$ is the least common digit. Addition and subtraction problems are more common, and among them, smaller nonzero digits are more likely. In multiplication problems, even numbers get an additional boost over odd numbers: that's because if either factor is even, the product is even.

Based on this, it looks some good starting guesses are

```
6+4*-1=2    or    7+2*-3=1    or    5+3*-1=2
```

which test four common numbers as well as three of the four possible operations. (It is very unlikely to encounter an equation with multiple operations, and if we assume that only one operation is present, these guesses will tell us which one that is.)

---

But we can also ignore digit frequency entirely: the two guesses

```
2*53=106    and    9+8/-4=7
```

contain all $14$ possible non-`=` symbols exactly once.

Comment: I get the idea, but how would you decide between testing 6 numbers, 1 operator and 4 numbers, 3 operators?

Comment: Are you sure unary negation is allowed?

Comment: @cst0313 I see it as being similar to finding the vowels in Wordle. It will help you as a human to know what the operators are, even if other things are more common.

Comment: @MJD It worked when I tested it.

Answer (score 1):

I enumerated all possible equations to create a dictionary thus reducing the game to Wordle for which I have already written an algorithm for. Using the principle of maximum entropy I get 48-32=16.

PS I have commutative answers turned off otherwise it wouldn't be equivalent to Wordle.

Answer (score -1):

I have found out, 9+8/-4=7 and 2*53=106 gives information about all the digits, thus enabling an educated guess in the third try.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).